# Reading tab seperated csv to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read tab seperated csv into a Dataframe, but only heading is delimited but not values
Below is my code

```
    import pandas as pd   
    import csv     
    dfs = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\LENOVO\Downloads\9.csv',sep='\t',engine='python')
```

Headers: Product Id Product Name Product Type UoM Weight(KG/Grams) Volume(Cubic meters) SAP ValuationClass Planner Deletion Flag SKU ID SKU Description

Input File:
[image]

my o/p is:
[image]

Columns got seperated but values didnt.
When i try to print first column in df, it throwing keyerror

I tried: lineterminator and all other previous similar responses, but nothing worked
Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: It looks like you have a mix of tabs and spaces as delimiters in the CSV. Try using `sep='\t\s'` instead. Also, I'm betting you don't need to `import csv`, unless you plan on doing something later that specifically requires `csv.writer` instead of `pd.DataFrame.to_csv`.

Comment: Thanks @cmaher but that doesnt seem working

Comment: Can you try copying the head of your input file into the body of your question?

Comment: @cmaher edited description

Comment: Has anyone tried tout use a regex as separator ? `sep=r"\s+"`

Comment: Have you tried to use the csv `sniffer` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand not using the `sep="\t"` argument but instead replace it by `delim_whitespace=True`

```
dfs = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\LENOVO\Downloads\9.csv',delim_whitespace=True,engine='python')
```

Comment: Might not work as it looks like one of the columns has spaces in it.

Comment: @Gwendal Grelier thrwing error as pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 20 fields in line 92, saw 22. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.